JetBrains WebStorm/IntelliJ IDEA GitLab MR bug
Recently, I've tried making a Merge Request to my self-hosted GitLab instance, and I keep getting an error that a merge request already exists for that, and links me to a closed and merged merge request, which doesn't make sense because there were changes to the branch after that MR has been merged.
How Can I fix this?

Merge Requests -> + Icon -> Select target branch and source branch -> Error encounter there.

You cannot, unfortunately. This is a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-81309/Gitlab-plugin-New-MR-cannot-be-opened-if-the-previous-one-is-merged
It will be fixed in the next release 24.2.
